# If property used for Scheduled annotation is empty, then use a default

Tags: java, spring, annotations, cron

I am writing a **Spring Batch** job and in the `Component` class I have:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${expression.from.property}")
public void runJob() {
        //code
}
```

This will grab a property from the properties file we have.  However, say this property file is missing from the property file, is there a way this can get a default `cron` expression on top of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the [Elvis operator](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-operator-elvis) to have a default value

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${expression.from.property ?:1 0 0 0 0 0}") // or whatever cron expression
public void runJob() {
        //code
}
```

Comment: So I have:  `@Scheduled(cron = "${expression.from.property} ?:0/5 * * * * 2013")`  However this gives an error:  `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Range exceeds maximum (8): 2013`.    My intention is it to run every 5 minutes in year 2013.

Comment: Try `/2013`. That would be a limitation of cron I believe.

Comment: Now I have:  `@Scheduled(cron = "${expression.from.property ?:0/5 * * * * /2013}")`.  I get this error:  `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""`.

Comment: @MohammadS. Sorry, it should be `*/2013` I think.

Comment: This is what I ended up using:  `@Scheduled(cron = "${expression.from.property ?: */5 * * * * */2013}")`.  It builds and deploys perfectly fine now.  Issue is my job doesn't run at all.  I've waiting 10-15 minutes (which should have 2-3 runs).

Comment: I actually forgot to come back to this once I figured it out.  The machine I was testing on was Windows, but the server the code was being deployed on was Linux (if I recall correctly).  This caused an issue because it went from Quartz to standard on the server.